# pandas: adding rows in a column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe like this,

```
Count
1
0
1
1
1
```

I want to **add N and N+1** in count column and store it in N, is it possible to do in pandas way?

result should like this, technically it is cumulative sum:

```
Counts
1
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a cumulative sum? Look into cumsum().

Comment: thank you @Spinor8

Comment: Could you be more clear in what you want to achieve?, how do you want your final dataframe to look like?

Comment: @Learner edited the question,

Comment: @Spinor8 please write your answer so that i can mark it.

Comment: Ok if you insist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cumulative sum function, cumsum().

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 0, 1, 1,1], columns=['Count'])

df['Counts'] = df['Count'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

giving you the desired output.

```
   Count  Counts
0      1       1
1      0       1
2      1       2
3      1       3
4      1       4
```